# Bug keep-alive delay

Tags: c++, sockets, keep-alive

This code connect using keep-alive to load lots of domains that share the same IP Address, but there's a bug after the first 25 domains, witch is a 30 seconds delay at every domain load! How to solve this?

```
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("123.123.123.123");
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeofaddr) != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to Connect", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
    char MTD[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nConnection:close\r\n\r\n";
    send(Connection, MTD, sizeof(MTD), NULL);
    char MOTD[1];
    int result;
    while ((result = recv(Connection, MOTD, 1, NULL)) > 0){
        std::cout << MOTD[0]; // ...
    }
    if (result == 0) {
        // end of stream
        std::cout << "end of stream";
        close(Connection);
    } else if (result < 0) {
        // error
        std::cout << "error";
        perror("recv"); // at least
        close(Connection);
    } else {
        std::cout << "data received";
        // data received, in MOTD[0..result-1]
    }
};
```

Comment: There's a bigger bug in your code: You have an array of size zero, and ask `recv` to write one byte into it, thereby overflowing it and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crawl lots of domains from the same IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061474/crawl-lots-of-domains-from-the-same-ip)

Comment: There are also a bug in your loop to receive the data, namely that you don't check for failure. Remember that `recv` returns `0` when the connection is closed, but `SOCKET_ERROR` (typically `-1`) when there's an error. In C++ all non-zero values are considered "true", so even if you have an unrecoverable failure you still continue as if nothing happened. And having a loop reading one byte at a time is really ineffective.

Comment: A small addendum to my previous comment: Socket functions returns `SOCKET_ERROR` on *Windows* using the native Windows socket API. The `SOCKET_ERROR` macro is Windows specific.

Comment: The line terminator in HTTP is defined as `\r\n`, not `\n`.

Comment: EJP Done. Some programmer dude Done, buffer size is one, code is supposed to detect error now, but i didnt actually saw any error, maybe the error detection is wrong, what you think?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: all BSD/POSIX-based socket API implementations, including WinSock, return -1 on socket function errors.  Windows just happens to have an additional `SOCKET_ERROR` constant that is defined as -1 for code readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
result=recv(Connection, MOTD, 1, NULL);
while(recv(Connection, MOTD, 1, NULL)){
```

This makes no sense whatsoever. The first `recv()` reads at least one byte into the buffer or sets `result` to zero or -1, whereupon you immediately ignore whatever it did and issue another `recv()`, whose result you ignore. It should be more like this:

```
while ((result = recv(Connection, MOTD, 1, NULL)) > 0){
    // data received, in MOTD[0..result-1]
}
if (result == 0) {
    // end of stream
    close(Connection);
} else if (result < 0) {
    // error
    perror("recv"); // at least
    close(Connection);
}
```

NB You aren't using HTTP keepalive at all. You are creating a new socket for every request and never closing it, at least until you use the code in this answer. You are *also* telling the server via the `Connection: keepalive` header to keep that connection alive, which will merely waste server resources. Either use HTTP keep-alive properly or close the socket after each request.

Comment: EJP Done, the recv return is end of stream, meaning it end without error. The 30 seconds delay on each domain load after 25 domains is still a problem.

Comment: Socket is being closed now since im using this code. Thought i was loading one keep-alive socket, how could i use it properly?

Comment: What part of 'either use HTTP keep-alive properly or close the socket after each request' didn't you understand?

Comment: What should change in my code for me to be using the "the HTTP keep-alive properly"?

Comment: @JavaOdd Too broad. For a start, re-using the connection instead of closing it. See the RFC.